# sqlite IFNULL() in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, ifnull

What is the equivalent of SQLite's `IFNULL()` in Postgres?

I have to following query (sqlite in Ruby):

```
SELECT ifnull(max(code_id) + 1, 1) 
FROM configentries 
WHERE configtable_id = ...
```

How should this look like if I want the same result with PostgreSQL?

Comment: try `coalesce` - it takes first not null value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, it's not to generate a unique ID.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

[try](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) `coalesce`:

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null

```
SELECT coalesce(max(code_id) + 1, 1) 
FROM configentries 
WHERE configtable_id = ...
```

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is that `COALESCE` function is what you can use in postgres.

`COALESCE` is better than `IFNULL` for several reasons:

- `COALESCE` is a standard SQL function (implemented in ~every RDBMS), while `IFNULL` is not standard, even if widely used.
- `COALESCE` can handle more than two operands. It returns the first non-NULL value. For example, `COALESCE(NULL, 'a', NULL)` returns `a`. `IFNULL` cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```sql
Select NULLIF(Max(code_id), 0) +1 
from  configentries 
WHERE configtable_id = ...
```

Comment: `nullif` and `ifnull` are very different functions. `ifnull` returns the second argument if the first is null while `nullif` returns null if the two arguments are equal. The original query would return 1 if `code_id` is null while the query with `nullif` would return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good, but wil only work in situations where only one row is returned.

If you want to query multiple rows and receive a default value if 0 Rows are found, you can use this:

```
SELECT example_field from "example_table" WHERE attribute='x'
UNION 
SELECT 'my_default_value' FROM  "example_table"  WHERE 
(SELECT example_field from "example_table" WHERE attribute='x'  LIMIT 1) is NULL
```