# Seek Highest Column Value From Today (Postgres, C++, QT)

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql

Edit: The below query doesn't work but the concept given in the answer still applies. Check here for how to fix the query [sqlite IFNULL() in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934155/sqlite-ifnull-in-postgres)

I have a table in Postgresql called 'transaction'. The primary key of this table is composite with (id, date), where id is an int and date is a timestamp. Every day, the first order starts at order #1. The next order that day would be #2, then #3, and so on until the next day with #1 again.

I'm not sure how I would change this SQL query to find the max transaction ID specifically from today then increment 1 to it.. or start again at 1 if there are no transactions today. So far the only thing I can do is just start at 1 if there are no transactions at all, or increment based on the highest ID across all dates.

```
/* Insert Transaction */
bool dbmanager::addTransaction(const int& custPhone=0, const int& totalCents=0, const qstr& items="",
                               const qstr& paymentType="", const int& tender=0, const int& change=0,
                               const int& cardNum=0, const int& cardExp=0, const int& cardCVV=0, QWidget* from=nullptr)
{
    QSqlQuery q;
    // TODO: This query increments the largest order number that exists across all dates. Make it so the order number is 1+ the max order number from today
    q.prepare("insert into pos_schema.transaction values( (select ifnull(max(id), 0) + 1 from pos_schema.transaction), NOW(), "
              ":phone, :total_cents, :items, :payment_type, :tender, :change, :card_number, :card_exp, :card_cvv);");
    q.bindValue(":phone",custPhone);
    q.bindValue(":total_cents", totalCents);
    q.bindValue(":items", items);
    q.bindValue(":payment_type", paymentType);
    q.bindValue(":tender", tender);
    q.bindValue(":change", change);


    QString cryptCardNum = crypt.encryptToString(qstr::number(cardNum));
    QString cryptCardExp = crypt.encryptToString(qstr::number(cardExp));
    QString cryptCardCVV = crypt.encryptToString(qstr::number(cardCVV));

    q.bindValue(":card_number", cryptCardNum);
    q.bindValue(":card_exp", cryptCardExp);
    q.bindValue(":card_cvv", cryptCardCVV);

    if (q.exec())
        return true;

    qDebug() << "Transaction Insertion Error:" << q.lastError().text();
    displayError("Insertion", from, q);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your sub-select

```
select ifnull(max(id), 0) + 1 from pos_schema.transaction
```

to something like

```
SELECT
    ifnull(max(id), 0) + 1
FROM pos_schema.transaction
WHERE
    pos_schema.transactiondate.date::date = CURRENT_DATE
```

Please note that your field `date` should really be of type `date` instead of `timestamp`. Otherwise your primary key does not protect you from inserting two duplicate IDs for the same date if they have different timestamps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll also change the column, good call. First time using postgres so this answered a few questions I had.